# Fontawesome is not working for changing the file path

Tags: html, css, svg

My fontawesome fonts is not working. It gives only a broken character.

My folder structure is::

```
Content
  fonts
    font-awesome.min.css
  html
    index.html
```

I have called fontsawesome css file as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../content/font-awesome.min.css" media="all" />
```

And I have called the fonts in the css file as bellow

```
*/@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';

src:url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');

src:url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'),

url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'),

url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'),

url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your file structure, you should reference your font file source like this: `href="../fonts/font-awesome.min.css"` (assuming that 'fonts' and 'html' are folders, from your specifications)

Comment: content is a folder having the fonts folder and font-awesome.min.css file and html is another folder having index.html file

Comment: then it should work like this, if you reference the font-awesome file from `index.html`